# How to get Media controls in Webview in android?

Tags: android, webview, mediacontroller

I am having Webview in android & currently playing youtube video from the Url. top of the webview, there is an `actionbar`. I want `actionbar` to be hidden when video is playing & `actionbar` to show when video is `onPause`. is there any way to get the current state of video playing inside the `webview`. or I can call `mediaControls` class in `webview`. Here is my code for webview:

```
        mVideoView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mVideoView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mVideoView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mVideoView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
        mVideoView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        mVideoView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

mVideoView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);